# How to enable multi-language selection in Phonegap-jQuery Mobile project?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, cordova

Hi I am a newbie to jQuery mobile , I have created a mobile application using **jQuery mobile** and **phonegap** , I want to enable the **multi-language** selection dropdown list in my app.I know how to add a dropdown list and putting items in list is easy.But the difficulty I am facing is to translate ..What are the possible ways to enable the translation ? for example the current language is English and while choosing another language (eg: Italian) I need to translate the complete page to Italian , How about using the **Google translator** ?

Comment: there are some Jquery Translator pluggings. heres some examples  ---   http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-translator-plugins/

Answer (score 0):

I recently built an app in German and English. Initially I gave user the option to select their desired language then stored their response as a localStorage.

Then I wrote all text for each page as string variables. So on each pagebeforeshow I did a quick check against the value in local storage and showed the relevant content from the corresponding string.

A more lightweight version might be to duplicate all pages in a sub directory. So for example all English lang files are in myapp/en and all German lang pages in myapp/de.

This keeps each page lightweight but makes keep track of all pages a little tricky as you get more languages. It'd also make the total size of your app larger. Also, yud have to work out the best way to switches users between languages.

I hope that gives you some ideas to work with..